# is it possible to nest an array_agg inside another array_agg

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a SQL table `message(application, type, action, date, ...)` and I would like to get all the actions for a type and all the types for an application in a single query if possible.

So far I have managed to get the result in two separate queries like so:

```sql
select application, array_agg(distinct type) as types from message group by application;
 application  |                                                           types                                                            
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 app1          | {company,user}
 app2          | {document,template}
 app3          | {organization,user}
```

and the second query:

```sql
select type, array_agg(distinct action) as actions from message group by type;
            type                      |                 actions                 
--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------
 company                              | {created,updated}
 document                             | {created,tested,approved}
 organization                         | {updated}
 template                             | {deleted}
 user                                 | {created,logged,updated}
```

The most obvious single query I could come up with so far is just:

```
select application, type, array_agg(distinct action) from message group by application, type;
```

Which would require some programmatic processing to build the `type` array.

What I wanted to do was something theoretically like:
`select application, array_agg(type, array_agg(action)) from message group by application, type` which isn't possible as is but I feel there is a way to do it. I have also thought about nesting the second query into the first one but haven't found how to make it work yet.

Comment: Arrays don't seem to be the right type here; what about `json`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=27a42c600eca25f3095f387bc67c3c3e)

You can create tuples (records): (col1, col2). So if col2 is of type array, you created (text, text[]). These tuples can be aggregated as well into array of tuples:

```
SELECT
    app,
    array_agg((type, actions))  -- here is the magic
FROM (
    SELECT
        app,
        type,
        array_agg(actions) actions
    FROM
        message
    GROUP BY app, type
) s
GROUP BY app
```

To get access, you have to explicitely define the record type at unnesting:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    -- your query with tuples
)s,
unnest(types) AS t(type text, actions text[]) -- unnesting the tuple array
```

---

Nevertheless, as stated in the comments, maybe JSON may be a better approach for you:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1136c0adf336af20af6d261ec3def868)

```
SELECT
    app,
    json_agg(json_build_object('type', type, 'actions', actions))
FROM (
    SELECT
        app,
        type,
        json_agg(actions) actions
    FROM
        message
    GROUP BY app, type
) s
GROUP BY app
```

Result:

```
[{
    "type": "company",
    "actions": ["created","updated"]
},
{
    "type": "user",
    "actions": ["logged","updated"]
}]
```

---

Another possible JSON output:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5ea0c95f9b532140997166014e294a5f)

```
SELECT 
    json_agg(data)
FROM (
    SELECT
        json_build_object(app, json_agg(types)) as data
    FROM (
        SELECT
            app,
            json_build_object(type, json_agg(actions)) AS types
        FROM
            message
        GROUP BY app, type
    ) s
    GROUP BY app
) s
```

Result:

```
[{
    "app1": [{
        "company": ["created","updated"]
    },
    {
        "user": ["logged","updated"]
    }]
},
{
    "app2": [{
        "company": ["created"]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Totally what I was looking for. Json is indeed more suited to the problem. Thanks